# How do i get body of message when using keyword mentions in teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, power-automate

in automate i have a flow. I am using "When keywords are mentioned".  the keyword i entered is "test"

I Selected, the team,channel,etc... all correctly.

when someone types "the test is a success". in that channel.  how do i get the full string "the test is a success"?

I have tried a few operations "get Messages", also tried a few dynamic content options and a few triggeroutput variations.  all either are blank or provide a long json string with subscription,channelId,teamId,etc.  but not the string I am trying to get.

Answer (score 0):

The `Get message details` action should help you ...

[image: Get Message Details]

In the body of the response, you'll clearly see the text that was entered to invoke the trigger.

[image: Response Data]

Answer (score 0):

Use Get message details, you will get message detail of that reply message. Then get your text with expression like this:
outputs('Get_message_details')?['body']['body']['plainTextContent']

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).